# How to pass parameters when initialising an angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I have an angular factory that contains a large amount of raw data (let's call it _fakeData), and I would like to expose a portion of the data depending on what parameters was passed during the initialisation (let's call it _exposedData).

The way I have done it right now is to create an init(language) method that will set this._exposedData to some value depending on the value of the language parameter, and all other methods in the factory will work off _exposedData.

However, for this to work, I will need to first call the init() method, then I'll need to check when init() has been called for all the other methods of the factory, which seems quite cumbersome.

I'm quite sure my current solution is very clunky, and wondering if someone could advise me on a better way to structure my factory?

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
.factory('TestFactory', function() {
    return  {
        //raw data set that should not be accessed or modified
        //access should be done through _exposedData instead
        _fakeData: {
            javascript: 'blah blah',
            ruby: 'blah blah blah',
            python: 'blah blah blah blah'
        },
        _isInitialised: false,
        init: function(language) {
            if (this._fakeData[language]) {
                this._exposedData = this._fakeData[language]; 
                this._isInitialised = true;
                return this;
            }
            throw new Error('Cannot initalise');
        },
        getData: function() {
            this._checkInitialised();
            return this._exposedData;
        },
        //checks whether init() has been called
        _checkInitialised: function() {
            if (!this._isInitialised) {
                throw new Error('Not initialised');
            }
        }

    }
})
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, TestFactory) {
    console.log(TestFactory.init('javascript').getData());
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3jJeE/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the `module.run` method for this. Call the init method inside run

```
myappModule.run(function(TestFactory) {
   TestFactory.init('javascript');
});
```

Comment: Thank you Chandermani for this! Can I ask how to pass a routeParams variable as a parameter to the init() method? For instance, if we had '/:language' as a routeParams variable, how would we use it with run?

Comment: `function(TestFactory)` params are injected so, you can do `function(TestFactory,$routeParams)`

Comment: HI @Chandermani, what would you suggest in order to create 2 instances of services with different parameters within the same module?

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module("TestApp",[]).provider("TestData", function() {
    var _fakeData =  {
        javascript: 'blah blah',
        ruby: 'blah blah blah',
        python: 'blah blah blah blah'
    };
    this._exposedData = {};
    this.setLanguage = function(x) {
      this._exposedData = _fakeData[x];
    }
    var _me = this;
    this.$get = function () { //this method should return what factory does
        return {
           ....
           getData: function () {
               return _me.exposedData;
        }
   }
});
angular.module("TestApp").config(function(TestDataProvider)
    TestDataProvider.setLanguage('javascript');
);
```

Hope I at least partially understood your question ... . ;-)

Comment: This is a better way but, if something like `$routeParams` need to be injected i don't think that would work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to move the `_fakeData` object, outside your `return` block, because otherwise your controller can just access it.

```
var _fakeData = {
        javascript: 'blah blah',
        ruby: 'blah blah blah',
        python: 'blah blah blah blah'
};
return {
...
};
```

Secondly, I would use the [module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module)'s `constant` method to define the language:

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
app.constant('language', 'javascript');
```

Then inject `language` in your factory, which has become much simpler:

```
app.factory('TestFactory', ['language', function(language) {
   var _fakeData = {
        javascript: 'blah blah',
        ruby: 'blah blah blah',
        python: 'blah blah blah blah'
   };
   return {
      getData: function() {
        return _fakeData[language];
      }
   };
}];
```

No need for an `init()` method anymore. Just use only getData() in your controller:

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, TestFactory) {
   console.log(TestFactory.getData());
});
```